# When to specify template parameters of a template function?

Tags: c++, linux, templates, g++

When I compile the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    template <class X, class Y>
    void foo(X& x, Y& y) {
        x.bar<Y>(y);
    }
};

class B {
public:
    template <class Z>
    void bar(Z& z) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

class C {
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    a.foo<B, C>(b, c);
}
```

I get this:

```
deduce.cpp: In member function ‘void A::foo(X&, Y&)’:
deduce.cpp:7:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
   x.bar<Y>(y);
          ^
```

If I don't specify the template parameter and let GCC deduce the template parameter of B::bar(), GCC happily compiles it.

At first, I thought, it means I shouldn't specify a template parameter for a template member function if compiler can deduce it.

However, when I call a.foo(), compiler should be able to deduce the template parameters as well.  But compiler doesn't complain about.

Hence, I am confused when specifying template parameters for a template member function is illegal, and when it is a must.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am using g++ 7.2.1.

Comment: @StoryTeller I failed to see the similarity between my issue and the post you mentioned.  Do you mind elaborating?  Thanks!

Comment: Just read the accepted answer. You can skip to "the template keyword".

Comment: I read the accepted answer.  I think the problem there was that the expressions were ambiguous to the compiler and so clarification is needed.  I fail to see the ambiguity in my expression above.  Any more hint?

Comment: Yes, C++ doesn't wait for there to be actual ambiguity, it demands of you to be specific, always, with dependent names. I believe that's covered to by one of the other answers. Been awhile since I read them all.